# What is the most portable and widely-supported way to embed and play audio files in PDF made with XeTeX?

Tags: beamer, media9, embedding, multimedia, audio

I wish to **embed audio files** in PDFs produced by **XeTeX** so that the user can click on a graphic (different for each recording) and hear the audio file. And I want the resulting PDFs to work in as many PDF viewers on as many OSes as possible. Also, I'd like the triggering graphic to remain visible during and after playback.

So far, I've tried the following:

- `beamer`'s `multimedia` package: Doesn't work with XeTeX.
- `attachfile` and `attachfile2`: Don't permit playback.
- `movie15`: Was superseded by `media9` 5+ ago.
- `media9`:

  - Audio in PDFs it produces doesn't work on any Linux PDF readers.
  - Doesn't work on modern Acrobat Reader versions (XI and later) without installing Flash plugin (and Flash is scheduled to be discontinued, to boot).
  - The files it produces can't even be loaded by Sumatra PDF Reader.
  - Foxit reader can play the audio, but it doesn't show the trigger images ever again (these are large pictures, unique to each audio file, and not a speaker or playback icon).

So in short, only one of these options even works partially, and it doesn't do so on Linux, on modern versions of Acrobat on Windows, or on many other Windows PDF viewers. Plus, it depends on a technology (Flash) that is slated to be discontinued in 2 1/2 years anyway.

What other options exist?

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[
    xetex,
    activate=onclick,
]{media9}

\begin{document}
    \includemedia[
        width=1\linewidth,
        addresource=test.mp3,
        flashvars={source=test.mp3 & autoPlay=false},
    ]{\includegraphics[height=15cm]{test.png}}{APlayer.swf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should add that the `media9` PDFs crash both Acrobat Reader 11 and Acrobat Reader DC with Flash Player installed, after listening to any given audio file more than two or three times.

Comment: Did you test also with pdflatex and lualatex as engine? And what is the format of the audio files? Can you provide an example and example code?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I need to use XeTeX. pdfLatex isn't viable because I need to use several hundred UTF-8 symbols with great frequency, and the backslash codes are illegible in such situations. And LuaLaTeX cannot properly typeset several of the most common diacritics I need.

Comment: I didn't asked you to switch, but if you tested with the engines.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Added an MWE to my original question. To test, rename any old PNG and MP3 to `test.png` and `test.mp3`, respectively.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just tried compiling with LuaLaTex. The resulting PDF does not work at all with Okular, gv, qPdfView or MuPDF (on Linux). It can't be loaded by Sumatra, plays sound but makes the triggering image disappear after the first play on FoxIt Acrobat XI and Acrobat Reader DC (Windows). And I got the exact same results with pdfLatex.

Comment: Your example doesn't compile.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Did you place a PNG file named `test.png` and an MP3 file named `test.mp3` in the same directory as the example file? If so, and the MWE still doesn't compile, kindly specify the error that is thrown.

Comment: The error is that \includegraphics is not defined. Didn't you test your example? Beside this: on windows I don't have problems with the examples in the documentation in the adobe reader. But the documentation is quite clear about the problems with the pdf viewers on linux -- and if the viewer don't support this, there is not much a package can do. You could only try the simple ` \href{run:test.mp3}{text displayed}` approach.

Comment: Let me take this discussion up to a higher level. While the `media9` solution apparently works okay for you, and is partially functional and partially broken for me, there's another issue here that makes `media9` a bad solution overall -- it depends on Adobe Flash, which is due to be retired in 2.5 years, is dead on Linux, and which has already been removed from many programs that once had it, including Adobe Reader on Windows and most web browsers.  **So rather than try to get a bad solution to work a bit better, I'm looking for a good solution.** What can people suggest in this regard?

Comment: That's not really a tex question. Imho the main question is if pdf is really the best format for what ever you want to achieve.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer "What's the most portable and widely-supported way to do something that *TeX does?" is absolutely a TeX question. It's also a recurring one. So please, if anyone knows a good way of doing this, do provide the answer!

Comment: "The main question is if pdf is really the best format for what ever you want to achieve".  Oh well... Powerpoint it is, I suppose. Not what I was hoping for.